# Serializing/Deserializing JSON in Dynamics CRM 2013/2015 Plugin

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dynamics-crm

I am developing a plugin for Dynamics 2015. The plugin requires some setup information which I thought would be a good idea to use a json object in the unsecure configuration. Also, there's an external system which is writing some json into a field in the entity that this plugin responds to which I need to extract information from.

I have tried to use JavascriptSerializer object to deserialize the json but I get a System.MethodAccessException, upon doing some research, I have found out that I can't use the JavascriptSerializer in sandbox mode.

I don't want to have to ILMerge Json.Net into my assembly, so is there any other way I can serialize/deserialize json in my plugin code?

Comment: Have you tried [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  The data contract serializers can be used in partial trust mode, according to [Types Supported by the Data Contract Serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), albeit with some limitations.

Comment: @JamesWood, I'm not a massive fan of XML, especially where there's a JSON alternative and nowadays, there usually is.

Comment: @dbc, thanks I'll try it in a bit and let you know whether to make your comment an answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: agree with @dbc, DataContractJsonSerializer can be used, I wrote a post about http://www.crmanswers.net/2015/02/json-and-crm-sandbox-plugins.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's how I solved this one

Given

```
 string wsData = string.Empty;
 plItem.GetType() == typeof(CategoryInfo);
```

and

```
 [DataContract]
 public class CategoryInfo{
    [DataMember]
    public string AllPropertiesToSerialize{ get; set; }
 }
```

then

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     var js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CategoryInfo));
     js.WriteObject(ms, plItem);
     ms.Position = 0;
     var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
     wsData = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Thanks to @dbc and @Guido Preite for the pointers